# waiting GetJSON async to finish

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, sharepoint, asynchronous

I have this simple javascript code that get spListItems from SharePoint using REST and populates a dropdown list.
I want to apply some bootstap style on it once the dropdown is populated. How can i determine that the population of dropdown is done/finsihed. so that I can apply style on the dropdown items.

```
       function populateDropDown(dropdownId, spList) {
        var url = "http://devportal/FormsRepository/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/" + spList;
        var dropdownControl = $('#' + dropdownId);
        $.getJSON(url, function (data) {
            $.each(data.d.results, function (key, value) {
                dropdownControl.append(
                    $('<option></option>').val(key).html(value.Title)
                );
            });
        });
      }
      //this lines does work properly as the dropdown is not populated yet
       $('.combobox').combobox();
```

Your time and help would be much appreciated.
Cheers

Answer (score 3):

Why not place

$('.combobox').combobox();

after the $.each loop?